# Get Angular $http return value into another oject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would like to get the return object from an HTTP request into another scope object so I can use it in HTML with `ng-repeat` directive. How can I get the returned object into a variable?

1. Call HTTP Function
2. Get Data
3. Store response
4. Make scope variable the value of the HTTP response

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ItemController',[
  '$scope', '$http', '$location',
  function($scope, $http, $location){

  var currentLocation = $location.path();

   $scope.getItem = function(){
      $http.get('path/to/json/file.json').then(
        function(response){
          $scope.results = response.data;
          console.log('item controller, item:', $scope.results);
        });

    };

    $scope.item = //MAKE THIS VALUE OF THE RETURN OBJECT FROM getItem
      console.log('scope.item', $scope.item);
    }
]);
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Mega",
    "last_name": "Man",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/75x75"
  }
]
```

**HTML**

Would like to be able to just have

```
<p>{{item.first_name}}</p>
<p>{{item.last_name}}</p>
<img ng-src="{{item.image}}"/>
```

**Updated JS Call**

```
$scope.getItem = function(){
    $http.get('path/to/json/file.json')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.results=data;
      console.log('$scope.results: ',$scope.results);
    }).error(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }).then(
      function(){
        $scope.item = $scope.results;
        console.log('$scope.item: ', $scope.results);
      });
  };
```

Comment: What you are asking for is similar to sending someone to pick up a pizza for you and then expecting it to be on the table before they left the driveway. You'll have to set `$scope.item` within a callback.

Comment: Ok so updated the JS call and running getting data from the `.then()` method with the initial call from the `.success()` method. Now that the date is there how does it get exposed into HTML?

Comment: exactly as you have it iirc. though the .then and $scope.results are redundant. I suspect `data` doesn't have exactly the structure you seem to think it does.

Comment: This is what doesn't make sense. `{{item}}` returns `[{"first_name":"mega",...` but `{{item.first_name}}` returns nothing

Comment: that makes perfect sense. you can't treat an array as if it is an object with key/value pairs and expect it to work.

Comment: Ok, so how to I filter out the array and get results like you would in the `ng-repeat` directive? I get that it's probably redundant what I'm doing but if there is a better way to make the call and expose it to HTML that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: well, to get the first item of an array, you would use `theArray[0]`. right? How many items does your array with one item have?

Comment: `$scope.item = $scope.results[0];` that was it, and the reason that it wasn't working earlier is because the callbacks weren't being used correctly

Comment: So .then() is removed and in the success callback just have `$scope.item=data[0];` and then expose to HTML with `{{item.property}}`. Thank you for for that. Side note is do you have any resources to help with promises and callbacks? Still can't wrap my head around them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: Haven't read this before and it looks really helpful thank you

Comment: Don't edit an answer into your question.  Just post it as an **actual** Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @zero298 I know, fixing it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways one way is to use `success` and `error` **callback** functions like:

```
 $http.get('path/to/json/file.json')
                .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
                  $scope.results =data;
          console.log('item controller, item:', $scope.results);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                  console.log(data);
                });
```

Another option is using `then` **promise** function like:

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: 'path/to/json/file.json').
        then(function(response) {
           $scope.results = response.data;
           console.log('item controller, item:', $scope.results);
        }, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still stuck even with changing the call. I need to be able to just say `{{item.name}}` or the like in HTML.  The only thing I can do is call the whole object `{{results}}` by your example and return an entire JSON object. I need to be able to call specifics like `{{results.name}}` or `{{results.image}}`

Comment: Just made an edit to my question, hopefully it's a bit more clear now on the expected outcome. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that was happening what getting callbacks to work correctly. Replaced the `.then()` method with `.success()` and `.error()`. Since the object that was getting called was an array it could not be parsed out in the HTML to get object properties. The other part that was needed was in the success callback to get the first object of the array with `$scope.results=data[0]`

```
$scope.getItem = function(){
  $http.get('path/to/json/file.json')
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.results=data[0];
    console.log('$scope.results: ',$scope.results);
  }).error(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how this code answers the question. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.